# What is the meaning of "select * from relational(owner.table)"?

Tags: oracle

We recently got some errors in our alert log of the form

```
301598: Tue Jul 16 03:58:29 2013
301599: ORA-01555 caused by SQL statement below 
301600: SELECT * FROM RELATIONAL(<owner>.<table>)
```

I know how to handle ORA-01555 errors, but I never encountered something like `SELECT * FROM RELATIONAL`. I looked in `DBA_OBJECTS`, but there is no such function/operator/whatever.

Googling for 'SELECT * FROM RELATIONAL' only returned questions related to ORA-01555.

So, my question is: What is the meaning of the RELATIONAL keyword here?

Comment: It seems that this is something deeply internal. Because support.oracle.com also shows only the same information that you already googled.

Comment: I am 99% certain this is for querying the XMLTYPE datatype, but I can't find the reference as obviously `relational` is a very difficult word to search DB documentation for.

Comment: @Gaius I don't think it's XMLTYPE related (the table doesn't contain an XMLTYPE column).

Comment: Found this, might help: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1042943?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: change your undo_retention parameter

Comment: What version of Oracle Database? SELECT version FROM v$instance;

Comment: @durette To be completely honest, I don't remember (it was 3 years ago). I *guess* it was a 11.2

Comment: @FrankSchmitt If you look for "XMLType_storage" in the SQL Language Reference, you'll see "OBJECT RELATIONAL" can appear in a storage clause. This is not the same as the RELATIONAL function here.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be inert. I tested this on XE 11 and found that it does nothing.

```
CREATE TABLE dbausers AS SELECT * FROM dba_users;

-- Function doesn't affect result set.
SELECT * FROM dbausers
MINUS
SELECT * FROM RELATIONAL(dbausers);

SELECT * FROM RELATIONAL(dbausers)
MINUS
SELECT * FROM dbausers;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was a deprecated alias to today's TABLE function for pipelined functions, but now I can't find my reference that says this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog article](http://www.hellodba.com/reader.php?ID=205&lang=EN) the specific hint `RELATIONAL` instructs the Query Optimizer to

> ... convert the object to a relational table, similar to RELATIONAL function ...

A [second article in the Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3812872) states that

> The RELATIONAL hint causes Oracle to unnest the object data and insert the attribute data itself rather than the object. The hints used can only be used by Oracle - which is why they are undocumented...

I think this is just an issue of a long running query, which is being exposed by the ORA-01555 error while internally using a query hint, which is undocumented.

Comment: Query hints are nested in /* comment blocks */. This appears to be something else.

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated by durette, this a useless cast. Most tables are RELATIONAL, and that's the default. However, Oracle also supports OBJECT tables (see the syntax on in [Oracle's CREATE TABLE docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6)), which explains the reason for the internal syntax. There isn't any reason to use RELATIONAL in a query but there is also no reason for it to fail. You should focus on the general fixes for ORA-01555. ORA-01555 usually means your UNDO segments are not sufficient to handle the rate of change in your database.

Are you able to reproduce this error on demand? How log does the offending query run before it fails? Or is your real question, "How do I track down the SQL that caused this error?"

Also, you didn't specify your Oracle version and patch level.

Comment: You realize, of course, that the question is almost six years old.

Comment: I wasn't interested in fixing the ORA-01555 (I know how to do that, as I mentioned in my question). I was just interested in the strange RELATIONAL function call / syntax, but my curiosity has waned over the years :-)

Comment: If you no longer want feedback on this question, you can delete it or accept an answer. As long as stack exchange considers this question unanswered, it will continue prompting people to help.